# How to test RequestDispacher with servlet runner?

Tags: unit-testing, servlets, http-unit

I have the the following code to test, I was trying with servlet runner by starting the servletunit client. Everything was fine except dispatcher.include(req,resp).It is throwing some exception at dispatcher. I don't know whether dispatcher is working with servlet runner or not.

Any suggestions are welcome.

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher1 =
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/header.jsp");
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher2 =
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/newclickmenu/clickMainMenu.jsp");

    BufferedHttpResponseWrapper bufferedHttpResponseWrapper = new BufferedHttpResponseWrapper(res);
    dispatcher1.include(req, bufferedHttpResponseWrapper);
    dispatcher2.include(req, bufferedHttpResponseWrapper);
```

Comment: What exception is it throwing?

Comment: com.meterware.httpunit.HttpInternalErrorException: Error on HTTP request: 500 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: Do you have jstl library in your classpath?

Comment: yes, i have jstl lib in classpath. The classpath is not a problem for me.if i remove dispatcher.include(), it is running fine.